# How can I display in my HTML file what is returned in my external JS script?

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a project that collects a piece of information from a website and returns that value in an HTML Document.

Here is what my HTML file looks like:

```
script type="text/javascript" src="website_fetch.mjs"></script>
            
    <section>
        <h2>Info on Google here</h2>
        <ul> 
            <article is= "site-status" name="Google" info = NEED RETURN VALUE FROM SCRIPT ABOVE ></article>
```

How can I get the returned value from this script? In the JS file, there is a return statement that I need to set equal to info in the `<article>` tag.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Scripts can’t return values, only functions can.

Comment: @Quentin yes but the function inside of the script that is external

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alter the script so that it selects the `article` tag you're interested in and populates the attribute. For example, if you have

```
// website_fetch.mjs
export const getGoogleInfo = async () => {
  // implementation goes here
  return someInfo;
};
```

you can change it to

```
// website_fetch.mjs
export const getGoogleInfo = async () => {
  // implementation goes here
  return someInfo;
};
getGoogleInfo()
  .then((result) => {
    document.querySelector('article[is="site-status"]').setAttribute('info', result);
  });
  // .catch(handleErrors); // don't forget this part - don't ignore errors
```

Your `getGoogleInfo` is asynchronous, so you have to wait for its Promise to resolve to a value before inserting the info.

But there's another problem. Your HTML is invalid. An `<article>` cannot be a child of a `<ul>`. An unordered list can only have children that are list items (`<li>`). Fix your HTML so that it's valid, so that none of your markup gets dropped or parsed incorrectly.

Live demo:

```js
// this is just to show that the article's info attribute is as desired:
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log(document.querySelector('section').innerHTML);
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script type="module">
export const getGoogleInfo = async () => {
  // implementation goes here
  return 'someInfo';
};
getGoogleInfo()
  .then((result) => {
    document.querySelector('article[is="site-status"]').setAttribute('info', result);
  });
</script>

<section>
  <h2>Info on Google here</h2>
  <article is="site-status" name="Google" info=N EED RETURN VALUE FROM SCRIPT ABOVE></article>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, this didn't do the trick. I put this after the script function right?

Comment: When I do this with a function, the syntax should be the same right?

Comment: If you fix the HTML so that it's valid, it looks to work for me - press "Run code snippet". The attribute gets populated as desired.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "when I do this with a function" - the `getGoogleInfo` is already a function.

Comment: Thank you for the edits. What should I replace `<ul>` with? I don't want to make the articles bulleted.

Comment: When I say function, I mean this: `async function getGoogleInfo() {`

Comment: Just remove the `<ul>` entirely, I suppose? Figure out what markup produces the sort of output that looks good, and that isn't invalid HTML, and use it

Comment: The <ul> formats the items for me. If I use any other tag, I believe it would screw with the format

Comment: What do you mean by "format"? Use CSS on the `<article>` if you want, but don't put invalid content inside a `<ul>` - see [MDN's article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul) on the sort of permitted content inside it

Comment: The code you just edited in has `<article is= "app-status"`, which is different from what you originally had of `<article is= "site-status"`. The selector `article[is="site-status"]` will only select articles with an `is` attribute of `site-status`. If your actual code has attributes that start with `app`, then just update the selector accordingly.

Comment: As you can see from the live demo in the answer, if the selector is correct, calling `setAttribute` on the element will populate it as desired.

Comment: Sorry about that. I just got confused with the example I was using. All attributes are correct on my end and still seems to not return what should be returned

Comment: Your `getGoogleInfo` function is asynchronous, which wasn't shown in your original code. You need to wait for the Promise it returns to resolve.

Comment: Right but when the page loads, it would never display it then

Comment: Sure it will, you just need to wait for it to resolve - it'll take a bit of time. You can't populate an element with data that your script has no access to yet. It depends on the content of the async function - might take a few milliseconds, might take 50 milliseconds, or something like that. Whatever it is probably won't take long enough to be an issue, unless you're dealing with an external API that's very laggy

Comment: Again, press "Run Code Snippet" in the answer to see the attribute being populated as desired. The code works.

Comment: I actually gave it a minute. It just doesn't display in the browser, just the console when using `console.log`. Should I maybe add something to the script to allow for it to pause the loading time of the page to allow for it to be updated?

Comment: Async shouldn't cause a problem

Comment: It does cause a problem because you were originally trying to retrieve its value immediately instead of waiting for the Promise to resolve. You need to call `.then` on the Promise to extract the value from it, as the answer shows.

Comment: The code in the answer populates the attribute as desired. The rest of this appears to be turning into a [chameleon question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions), so I'm going to stop commenting. If you're having issues separate from what you're originally asking, they should go into a new question.